# Lose EF Code First Migration when working on different TFS branches?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, coldfusion, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We are using TFS and have different branches for our Dev.

1. in the branch A we made a migration to change a column size
2. in the branch B we made a migration to add a new table. This branch doesn not know about the branch A modification !!
3. both modification are merged to the main branch.

When I do an update database, it does the 2 migration but at the end tells me there is pending changes. If I do an Add-Migration, it creates the same as the 1st migration (in branch A).

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending 
>       changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model 
>       changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>       DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic
>       migration.
>       You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a 
>       code-based migration.

Is it because something is missing in  the content of the property Target de IMigrationMetadata of my last migration since it didn't know about the 1st one ?

Is it possible to handle migrations in different TFS branches?

Comment: are you synchronizing just migration files - or also the databases as well? You might be better off just sync-ing the model/classes files, w/o migrations, and running Add-Migration to generate specific 'local' migration for each developer.

Comment: is migration 1 listed as run in the _migrationhistory table?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An EF migration step contains a metadata file, that has a signature of the model that is the result of the migration step. The problem when merging is that the signature of the migration done in branch B doesn't include the stuff done in the migration in branch A. As long as the migrations are in the branches, this is correct. When merging it becomes wrong.

To remedy it, you have to regenerate the meta-data of the latter migration with

```
add-migration MyMigrationName
```

Running `add-migration` on an existing migration without the `-force` parameter will regenerate just the metadata.

I wrote an in depth walk-through of a merging scenario in the [EF Migrations and a Merge Conflict](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/ef-migrations-and-a-merge-conflict/) post on my blog.

Comment: "without the -force parameter will regenerate just the metadata" - in my case is generates a migration with '1' added to the name :(

Comment: @Tymski That's if the existing migration is applied. First update-database -targetmigration <Previousmigration>

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Anders Abel's answer and for those of you who are having the issue when trying to regenerate the last migrations metadata causing EF to create a separate migration with a 1 appended to it.

You must include the full date/time stamp.

E.g.

If the filename of your previous migration is **201701011322_MakeChangesToPotatoTable**

Then you must include the fullname properly in the "Add-Migration" command.

I.E.

```
Add-Migration 201701011322_MakeChangesToPotatoTable
```

Answer (score 0):

With EF core, the current state of the model is kept in ***ModelSnapshot.cs.  It is normally merged so you don't have anything to do... unless there is a conflict.