# Merging multiple migrations Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following scenario-

I am working in a branch where I have added 3 new migrations - for convention I will name them

```
Migration A
Migration B
Migration C
```

When trying to merge with `master` it turns out there are 4 new migrations, that are not chronologically ordered (merged from another branch). What I mean is the following

```
new Migration from master 1
existing Migration in both branches
existing Migration in both branches
new Migration from master 2
new Migration from master 3
new Migration from master 4
existing Migration in both branches
existing Migration in both branches
```

And when merging I get the following scenario

```
new Migration from master 1
existing Migration in both branches
existing Migration in both branches
new Migration from master 2
new Migration from master 3
new Migration from master 4
existing Migration in both branches
existing Migration in both branches
Migration A
Migration B
Migration C
```

Now obviously Entity Framework will not let me update the database since it thinks the model is wrong - when adding a new migration it generates the changes from the aforementioned 4 new migrations from `master`.

The real problem is that I can not revert back to an existing migration and then re-scaffold to update the metadata since they are not chronologically ordered
(as suggested per accepted [answer](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/ef-migrations-and-a-merge-conflict) in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171658/lose-ef-code-first-migration-when-working-on-different-tfs-branches)).

I have tried to `update-database -target` back to the migration before `new Migration from master 1` and then `Add-Migration <timestamp> new Migration from master 1` to re-scaffold it but I get the `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending....` exception.

I do not really want to add a blank migration to fix this but rather find a clean and good solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research the solution was to update database to the migration before the last one and then re-scaffold the last migration.

```
update-database -target Migration B
add-migration <timestamp>_Migration C
```